# Radial Set InteractableToggleCollection and Deselecting

Tags: unity-game-engine, mrtk

pretty new to MR development so bear with me here

I am trying to use the Radial Set to change states within my scene.

How I initially understood it's use is that the OnDeselect() function would be called on all other children part of the radial set that is not being pressed. But this seems to be not the case, as any function I add to the OnDeselect() is not being executed.

For example:
In a set of

- Radial A (active)
- Radial B

Selecting Radial B would trigger Radial B's onSelected event (which it does) and Radial A's onDeselected event (which it doesn't)

[image]

I have also tried setting the Can Deselect to true on the radial buttons Interactable Script, but this is just overridden at run-time and set back to false.

If I am approaching this the wrong way and there is a better alternative to achieve what I am intending to please let me know

Thanks :)

Comment: Can you confirm the other toggle is actually deselected (visually)? Currently they seem to act as two independent toggles...

Comment: Yes, it is indeed being deselected visually, so that only one radial button is selected at any time.

Answer (score 1):

Yes unfortunately, the InteractableOnToggleReceiver executes when there is a "click" fired.

With the InteractableToggleCollection component, each Interactable is self toggled via the property "IsToggled" and the "CanDeselect" property is force disabled. This is to ensure that one radial prefab is enabled at all times.

I have filed an issue on github here to track
https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/issues/7165

As a temporary workaround, you can listen to InteractableToggleCollection.OnSelectionEvents via code to know when the radial has updated